# Update mysql if statements (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to build an easy textbased game in php to learn php. The problem is how do i UPDATE database table if certain parameters i met.
1 barracks cost 3000 and i want to check if the user got 3000 money or more. Only update then or say you need more money.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "phpsamples";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = UPDATE tbl_registered_users
SET     barracks = IF(money = '>3000', barracks + 1)
WHERE   id = 1";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
  echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
  echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: `UPDATE ... SET barracks = barracks + (money > 3000), money = money - 3000 * (money > 3000) WHERE ...`

Comment: Akinas set works, but you can do your code that way, you have to check it prior to update

Comment: @nbk no you don’t have to check upfront, you can also implement that check in the WHERE clause of the UPDATE statement.

Comment: he wants to decline the update, if the money isn't enough, that happoens if money is smaller than 300 no baracks is increased, but the update commands will not give an **error** so if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE)  will not be triggert

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE table SET
   money = money - 3000,
   barracks = barracks + 1
WHERE id=1 
  AND money>= 3000
```

This will upp the `barracks` and reduce the money for user `id=1` **ONLY** if he has 3000 or more money.

To check if the update applied (i.e. if the user indeed has the money) you can use [mysqli_affected_rows()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php), which

> Returns the number of rows affected by the last INSERT, UPDATE,REPLACE or DELETE query.

If it returns `0` there was no update because the `WHERE` clause wasn't met, so you can send the 'not enough money' message.

If it returns `1` the `WHERE` clause was met and the user has one more barracks.

Comment: @RonvanderHeijden You're right, but I assume that if the user doesn't exist he can't login at all so he'll never come to the point of buying something.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to fetch the specific user by user id. Then check the parameters and update.

```
$query = $conn->query("select * from tbl_registered_users where id = 1");
if ($query->num_rows > 0) {
    $row = $query->fetch_assoc();
    if($row["money"] > 3000) {
       $conn->query("update tbl_registered_users set barracks = barracks + 1 where id = 1");
    }
}
```